# Stripping hex bytes with sed - no match

Tags: regex, macos, sed, hex

I have a text file with two non-ascii bytes (0xFF and 0xFE):

```
??58832520.3,ABC
348384,DEF
```

The hex for this file is:

```
FF FE 35 38 38 33 32 35 32 30 2E 33 2C 41 42 43 0A 33 34 38 33 38 34 2C 44 45 46
```

It's coincidental that FF and FE happen to be the leading bytes (they exist throughout my file, although seemingly always at the beginning of a line).

I am trying to strip these bytes out with sed, but nothing I do seems to match them.

```
$ sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9\,]//g' test.csv 
??588325203,ABC
348384,DEF

$ sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9\,]//g' test.csv 
??.
```

Main question: How do I strip these bytes?
Bonus question: The two regex's above are direct negations, so one of them logically has to filter out these bytes, right? Why do both of these regex's match the 0xFF and 0xFE bytes?

*Update*: the direct approach of stripping out a range of hex byte (suggested by two answers below) seems to strip out the first "legit" byte from each line and leave the bytes I'm trying to get rid of:

```
$sed 's/[\x80-\xff]//' test.csv
??8832520.3,ABC
48384,DEF

FF FE 38 38 33 32 35 32 30 2E 33 2C 41 42 43 0A 34 38 33 38 34 2C 44 45 46 0A
```

Notice the missing "5" and "3" from the beginning of each line, and the new 0A added to the end of the file.

**Bigger Update**: This problem seems to be system-specific. The problem was observed on OSX, but the suggestions (including my original sed statement above) work as I expect them to on NetBSD.

**A solution**: This same task seems easy enough via Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^\xFF\xFE//' test.csv
58832520.3,ABC
348384,DEF
```

However, I'll leave this question open since this is only a workaround, and doesn't explain what the problem was with sed.

Comment: Your perl example helped me enourmously, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed 's/[^ -~]//g'
```

or as the other answer implies

```
sed 's/[\x80-\xff]//g'
```

See [section 3.9](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/sed/sed_12.html) of the sed info pages.  The chapter entitled escapes.

**Edit** for OSX, the native lang setting is en_US.UTF-8

try

```
LANG='' sed 's/[^ -~]//g' myfile
```

This works on an osx machine here, I'm not entirely sure why it does not work when in UTF-8

Comment: Thanks - but this doesn't seem to work for me. When I run this on the test file the only change is a carriage return (x0A) appended to the end of the file.

Comment: The last comment was in regard to the first approach. 
The second one strips off the first legit character (5) but leaves the FF and FE bytes. It doesn't make sense to me why...

Comment: Oh.  Are you outputting the result of sed to a new file, i.e.
`sed 's/[^ -~]//g' test.csv > test1.csv`  sed itself does not change the file, it outputs a changed version to stdout.

Comment: Yes, I'm just doing it in-line for purposes of posting here.

Comment: @Greg Which version of osx?, and have you replaced the original sed?

Comment: This is v10.6.4, and is the original sed AFAIK

Comment: See my update, the problem is that LANG=en_US.UTF-8  (assuming perhaps wrongly that you're a usian).  I have no idea why that screws things up.

Comment: I'm going to ask a question as to why it screws up.

Comment: @deinst it screws up (at least as I understand it) because the FF FE isn't treated as part of the content of the file, but as formatting metadata -- and hence the editing rules don't get applied to it.  Similarly, if you did `sed 's/.//g' | xxd` you'll get `fffe 0a0a` because the 0A (linefeeds) aren't part of the lines, they're line terminators, and hence don't have the "delete everything" rule applied.

Comment: @Gordon  Thanks, I am beginning to understand the subtleties of UTF-8. Give me back the days when men were men and everything was ascii.

Answer (score 4):

This will strip out all lines that begin with the specific bytes FF FE

```
sed -e 's/\xff\xfe//g' hexquestion.txt
```

The reason that your negated regexes aren't working is that the [] specifies a character class.  sed is assuming a particular character set, probably ascii.  These characters in your file aren't 7 bit ascii characters, as they both begin with F.  sed doesn't know how to deal with these.  The solution above doesn't use character classes, so it should be more portable between platforms and character sets.

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't know that about the []. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to solve my particular problem.

Comment: I re-read your question and updated my answer to catch all occurances of this pattern.  Also, it turns out that this solution works for me on cygwin, Redhat linux 4.8 but fails on an older Redhat system and Solaris 9.  Older versions of sed might not be able to deal with non-ascii.

Answer (score 3):

The `FF` and `FE` bytes at the beginning of your file is what is called a "byte order mark (BOM)". It can appear at the start of Unicode text streams to indicate the endianness of the text. `FF FE` indicates UTF-16 in Little Endian

Here's an excerpt from the FAQ:

> Q: How I should deal with BOMs?
>
> A: Here are some guidelines to follow:
>
> 1. A particular protocol (e.g. Microsoft conventions for `.txt` files) may require use of the BOM on certain Unicode data streams, such as files. When you need to conform to such a protocol, use a BOM.
> 2. Some protocols allow optional BOMs in the case of untagged text. In those cases,
>
>    - Where a text data stream is known to be plain text, but of unknown encoding, BOM can be used as a signature. If there is no BOM, the encoding could be anything.
>    - Where a text data stream is known to be plain Unicode text (but not which endian), then BOM can be used as a signature. If there is no BOM, the text should be interpreted as big-endian.
> 3. Some byte oriented protocols expect ASCII characters at the beginning of a file. If UTF-8 is used with these protocols, use of the BOM as encoding form signature should be avoided.
> 4. Where the precise type of the data stream is known (e.g. Unicode big-endian or Unicode little-endian), the BOM should not be used. In particular, whenever a data stream is declared to be UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE or UTF-32LE a BOM must not be used.

#### References

- [unicode.org/FAQ/UTF BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
- [Wikipedia/Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

#### Related questions

- [Why would I use a Unicode Signature Byte-Order-Mark (BOM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045663/why-would-i-use-a-unicode-signature-byte-order-mark-bom)
- [Difference between Big Endian and little Endian Byte order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701624/difference-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-byte-order)

Answer (score 2):

To show that this isn't an issue of the Unicode BOM, but an issue of eight-bit versus seven-bit characters and tied to the locale, try this:

Show all the bytes:

```
$ printf '123 abc\xff\xfe\x7f\x80' | hexdump -C
00000000  31 32 33 20 61 62 63 ff  fe 7f 80                 |123 abc....|
```

Have `sed` remove characters that aren't alpha-numeric in the user's locale. Notice that the space and 0x7f are removed:

```
$ printf '123 abc\xff\xfe\x7f\x80'|sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]//g' | hexdump -C
00000000  31 32 33 61 62 63 ff fe  80                       |123abc...|
```

Have `sed` remove characters that aren't alpha-numeric in the C locale. Notice that only "123abc" remains:

```
$ printf '123 abc\xff\xfe\x7f\x80'|LANG=C sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]//g' | hexdump -C
00000000  31 32 33 61 62 63                                 |123abc|
```

Comment: Thank you - I was trying to strip a specific byte (`0xC3`) from a file, and nothing worked, until I did `LANG=C sed -b -i'' 's/[\xc3]//g' mytext.txt`

Comment: @sdbbs: You shouldn't need the square brackets since you're selecting one character and not any-of-several.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, the Byte Order Mark is probably being read as a single word. Try either `sed 's/^\xfffe//g'` or `sed 's/^\xfeff//g'` depending on endianess.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hex codes with \xff \xfE and replace it by nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you may used ed(1):

```
printf '%s\n' H $'g/[\xff\xfe]/s///g' ',p' | ed -s test.csv

printf '%s\n' H $'g/[\xff\xfe]/s///g' wq | ed -s test.csv  # in-place edit
```