# LANG and sed on OSX

Tags: macos, utf-8, sed

In a recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435370/stripping-hex-bytes-with-sed-no-match/3435406#3435406) it was noted that on OSX running sed on a non ascii file gave strange results.  For instance if you do (/usr/bin/cal is a random binary file)

```
sed 's/[^A-Z]//' /usr/bin/cal
```

`sed` will remove all of the printable characters other than A-Z, but many nonprintable characters remain.  If however, you do

```
LANG='' sed 's/[^A-Z]//' /usr/bin/cal
```

only A-Z (and newlines) are output.  Why?

Normally `LANG=en-US.UTF-8`  What is going on?  I cannot see anyway that the output of sed could be considered correct in UTF-8.  Is it broken, or is there some notion of working that I do not understand?

I know that the OSX sed is conforming to POSIX, and is therefore different from the beloved GNU sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary data, such as the contents of /usr/bin/cal, are not UTF-8, and so will confuse any code that reads it as if it was. In particular, any byte with the high bit set (e.g., >= 128) will be interpreted as part of a multi-byte sequence representing a single character, and will thus be elided from the output. Not all sequences of bytes with the high-bit set are valid UTF-8, so things will get quite confused, but this probably explains why some non-printable characters remain but (possibly) not others.

In short: if you want to use text-oriented tools on binary data, don't.