# Hex codes in sed - not behaving as expected on OSX

Tags: macos, sed, hex

The answer to my question may exist on SO, but I have honestly looked hard and can't find it. The closest I got was [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435370/stripping-hex-bytes-with-sed-no-match) but I could not reproduce their results on my machine (OSX 10.7.5, using `bash`).

Here is the issue reduced to its essence: I can't get `sed` to interpret `\xnn` (e.g. `\x41` for `A`) as hex characters. What's driving me nuts in particular is this:

```
echo -e '\x41'
```

results in `A` - so the OS and its functions understand my hex code...

```
echo -e '\x41' | sed 's/A/B/'
```

results in `B` - as expected, since the hex code was converted to `A` before `sed` saw it

But

```
echo A | sed 's/\x41/B/'
```

results in `A` - I would have expected `B`

I have tried things like

```
echo A | LANG='C' sed 's/\x41/B/'
```

results in `A`

```
echo A | LANG='' sed 's/\x41/B/'
```

ditto...

```
echo A | sed 's/[\x41]/B/'
```

results in `A`

BUT...

```
echo A | sed 's/[\x41-\x41]/B/'
```

results in `B` ???

Am I being completely stupid? Or is there really something strange with `sed`? It can apparently interpret the hex code in a range, but I can't get it to be interpreted as a single character. What am I missing?

Please note - I am looking for answers that both explain why the above is behaving the way it is, and for ways to make it possible to insert a *single hex code* anywhere in a `sed` string, *on the OSX platform*. This means both in the "search", and in the "replace" part of the `s/` command.  Because I have obviously shown I can search for a single character with [\xnn-\xnn]; that's not the answer I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no general concept of what "the OS and its functions understand" -- each program, function, etc understands its own particular set of metacharacters, escapes, etc. And it just happens that `sed` doesn't do hex codes. But bash does (if you ask it to), so you can have it translate them before calling `sed` with `$''`:

```
$ echo A | sed $'s/\x41/B/'
B
```

Note that this also interprets other escape sequences before passing them to `sed`, so if you want to pass any escapes to `sed`, you need to double-escape them, or switch quote modes so only the relevant portion is in `$''`:

```
$ echo A | sed $'s/\\(\x41\\)/B\\1/' # double-escapes for sed's escape sequences
BA
$ echo A | sed 's/\('$'\x41''\)/B\1/' # equivalent with different quote modes
BA
$ echo A | sed 's/\(A\)/B\1/' # simplest equivalent version
BA
```

And if you want to interpret a hex escapes in a variable, rather than constant, string, then you pretty much have to use the shell's `printf` builtin:

```
$ hex=41
$ echo A | sed "s/$(printf "\x$hex")/B/"
B
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If "sed doesn't do hex codes", how do you explain my last example- it *looks* like sed is understanding hex in the range expression ...

Comment: Any elaboration on how to use hex encoding in the substitute part of the sed expression (the second part)?  I tried: `echo -ne 'a\x0db' | sed $'s/\x0d/\x0a/g' | hexdump -C` and `echo -ne 'a\x0db' | sed $'s/\x0d/\\x0a/g' | hexdump -C` to no avail.  Otherwise, this was what I was hoping to find.

Comment: @mpettis: This may be different in other versions of sed, but in OS X's version you need to escape any linefeeds in the replacement string (and the escape, because of the `$'...'` needs to be escaped itself): `echo -ne 'a\x0db' | sed $'s/\x0d/\\\x0a/g' | hexdump -C`

Comment: @GordonDavisson : Thanks!  I didn't try the triple-escape.  So, I need the first \ to escape the second escape because it is inside of `$''`, and after processing in that, I get `\\x0d`, which is the escaped version that gets passed to sed, right?  Trying to wrap my head around how the \ gets processed...

Comment: @mpettis: Not quite; bash processes "\\" into "\", and "\x0a" into an actual linefeed, so what sed sees is "\<LF>" (where "<LF>" is an actual linefeed).

Comment: I use a sed file `sed -f convert.sed` where I just vi-ed CTRL-V my characters to search for (I needed to replace UTF-8 strings) which works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

@GordonDavisson gave me inspiration to try two more things...

First off - I suddenly wondered if I was misinterpreting the output of

```
echo A | sed 's/[\x41-\x41]/B/'
```

I assumed this meant that `sed` understood the `\xnn` codes in a range, but I was wrong.  When I tried

```
echo A | sed 's/[\x40-\x40]/B/'
```

I **still** got an output of `B` , although I thought I wasn't including `A` (`\x41`) in the range any more.  Clearly, `sed` was interpreting my range in some other way than I expected.  This was resolved by looking at the `man re_format` page more carefully. It says

> [...] all other special characters, including `\', lose their special
>   significance within a bracket expression.

But then I got inspiration: if `echo -e` can expand the string, maybe I can use it to feed the string I want to `sed`...

```
echo "This?" | sed `echo -e 's/\x54\x68\x69\x73\x3F/\x59\x65\x73\x21/'`
```

Produces `Yes!`

```
echo "That?" | sed `echo -e 's/\x54\x68\x69\x73\x3F/\x59\x65\x73\x21/'`
```

Produces `That?`

Of course in this case the `\xnn` characters represent just plain ASCII - decoding the string just gives `'s/This?/Yes!/'` , but it does establish the principle of inserting hex characters into a string for `sed`. The only thing this doesn't help clear up is "what happens if your echo statement prints characters that would need to be escaped in `sed`. And it still doesn't address my fundamental question - "how do I insert hex characters directly into a `sed` string. I still suspect it is possible... even more so after reading the documentation on `sed` (which claims to use "old" regular expressions, although the -E flag can make it use "extended" expressions, and directs the user to the `re_format` man page for details; and the `re_syntax` page, which is referenced by `re_format`. Between these, it really does look like adding a hex string should work directly...

I added this information as an "answer" rather than an "edit" to my question, as I believe it *begins* to answer my question... Looking forward to comments!