# How to get rid of horizontal whitespace between divs?

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me get rid of the horizontal white space between two divs. I am using twitter bootstrap and the white space issue can be seen at http://www.areyoumoving.com.au between the hero image and the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your page through a hex viewer. It is certainly a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) before the footer which means your footer file has these chars in the beginning:

%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A**%EF%BB%BF**%3Cfooter

[image]

Here are many ways to remove it - not just AWK

[Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark)

PS: [Why would I use a Unicode Signature Byte-Order-Mark (BOM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045663/why-would-i-use-a-unicode-signature-byte-order-mark-bom)

Comment: Yeah, how do I remove it?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I had never heard of the BOM before, I use Sublime Text 3 so I re-opened and saved my files with UTF8 encoding without the BOM

Comment: Yeah, it is very annoying and surprising. One of those things to never forget :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using some "col-lg/md/sm/xs" classes from bootstrap... these classes have a pre-defined margin / padding into their styles.

Just override these properties to get rid of them, add these lines in your css file :

```
#yourIdentifier{
    margin:0; //or top/left/right/whatever
}
#yourIdentifier{
    padding:0; //whatever ;)
}
```

You may sometimes have to add "!important" tag (end of css line) to be sure your edits are really taken into account.

Comment: I am using those classes, however upon inspecting the problem it isn't showing up like a margin or padding problem. There are 2 random quotation marks appearing in the markup after it is rendered

Comment: these random quotations come from the fact that you're using ::before & ::after properties. The style of these "pre-defined" before/after just look like setting the content to ""...

Answer (score 0):

There is any trash before `<footer>`, probably `BOM` (if you include footer from the single file).

Remove BOM, save the file again and it will be okay.